# Use build quality in TFS to control deployment pipeline

Tags: deployment, continuous-deployment

I'm looking for a little info on how to use TFS's Build Quality to control our build and deployment process. Say I have following linear deployment pipeline

(Check in) -> Build -> run unit test -> run integration test -> release to xx environment -> release to yy environment

The first 3 steps are part of the CI process (either a single team build or 3 individual) and the last 2 are manually triggered events.

My questions is rather broad - but can I use Build Quality to control my deployment pipeline ***within the same changeset***. A little like how ThoughtWorks GO works

[image]

So lets say that unit- and integration tests went through and the application is ready for release to environment xx (manually). Can I use the build quality feature to deploy the corresponding changeset to environment xx? 
I haven't seen any good approach for creating a deployment pipeline or application life cycle management with TFS. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [TFSDeployer](http://tfsdeployer.codeplex.com/).

**Project description**: TFS Deployer enables the Team Build's Quality field in Team Foundation Server to be used to trigger a PowerShell script to be executed to automatically deploy a build to multiple environments.

Comment: I've read a little about and it may suit some of the needs. I'll try and install it and take it for a test run.